# How to determine if Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design is being used?

Tags: c#, .net-core, sourcegenerators

I have a reasonable (although imprecise) idea as to what source generators do, but I have several projects in a solution that reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` and the projects don't (to the best of my knowledge) have any source generators.

Given that this is source generation, I might be mistaken about the usage or it could be used indirectly.  How can I determine whether it is safe to remove the reference?  There isn’t anything else in the CodeGeneration namespace in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

That package is used to scaffold various aspects in web projects:

- [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-without-existing-authorization)
- [Scaffold Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-the-movie-model)

Probably those projects have been created/updated with [scaffolding](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding#aspnet-scaffolding), that is the reason of the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package

It seems that is needed only if developing via cli:

[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design - Code Generation tool for ASP.NET Core. Contains the dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator command used for generating controllers and views.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/)

[dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator is only required to scaffold from the command line, it's not needed to use scaffolding with Visual Studio.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator)

Comment: I saw that, and to test it I removed the reference and the dll, and then created a controller based on a viewmodel, and it successfully created the controller, even though the dll had been removed. But that app doesn’t have a dbcontext which might explain the difference.

Comment: the dll is needed to create the controller during development only if you use scaffolding to create the code, the code generation happens during development. Once the code is created is just like any other controller that you have written by hand. C#9 SourceGenerators is another feature, not related to your question, where code creation happens during build time

Comment: I phrased that badly.  I deleted the dll, then used scaffolding to create a controller, and that worked. Not saying you are wrong, just some part I still need to work on  understanding.  Not sure why the IDE would have to require the application being developed to have a dll installed in order to do its thing.

Comment: I see, I digged a little bit more about it, I'll add some info in the answer

Comment: removed the reference and then tried to add a razor page via the scaffolding menu in the "Add new Scaffolded Item" right click context menu -- unlike when I added a controller, this added the nuget package for the Design dll and it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally safe to remove a reference which doesn't prevent compilation when absent.

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` seems like a very weird thing to reference in a project - I believe it's used for generating the default code for views & controllers so I'm pretty sure it can be removed as long as it still compiles.